# Javascript Object-Oriented-Programming

Tags: javascript

I found a Module pattern in JS:

```
<script>
var MODULENAME = (function(my, $) {
    my.publicVar = "5";
    my.publicFn = function() {};
    return my;
}(MODULENAME || {}, jQuery));
</script>
```

However I cannot perform instantiation. Does the module pattern allow for that?

Comment: Where do you "find" such things?

Comment: What do you want to instantiate? MODULENAME is assigned the result of a self-executing function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript for more details.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `instantiation`? You have essentially created a static class within the var.

Comment: The javascript module pattern is essentially a singleton (meaning it has only one instance). It has been instantiated. [Javscript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module object can contain anything. Perhaps you're looking for including a constructor in it:

```
var MODULENAME = (function(my, $) {

    var privateVar = 10;
    my.SomeConstructor = function() {
        this.publicVar = 5;
    }
    my.SomeConstructor.prototype.someMethod = function() {};
    my.SomeConstructor.prototype.getPrivate = function() { return 10; };

    return my;
}(MODULENAME || {}, jQuery));

var instance = new MODULENAME.SomeConstructor();
instance.publicVar;    // 5
instance.privateVar;   // undefined
instance.getPrivate(); // 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Instantiantion means basically that you'll run a **function** using `new`.

So maybe you're looking for this?

```
var Some = function (param) {
  var somePrivateVar = 'private';
  this.somePublicVar = 'public';

  this.method = function () {
    return param;
  };
};

var some = new Some('abla');
console.log(some.method());
// some.somePrivateVar === undefined
// some.somePublicVar === 'public'
```

In your case `MODULENAME` is an object (object, not a function) with `publicVar` and `publicFn`. It's not meant to be instantiated the same way you wouldn't call `new jQuery()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also with prototype Inheritance :

```
var MyClass = function(name)
{
//sharing name within the whole class
this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.getName = function(){
return this.name;//now name is visible to getName method too
}

MyClass.StaticMethod = function()
{
console.log("Im Static");

// and since is not in prototype chain, this.name is not visible
}

    var myclass = new MyClass("Carlos");
    console.log(myclass.getName())//print "Carlos"
MyClass.StaticMethod()// print "Im Static"
myclass.StaticMethod() // error
```

Se all [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)